# How can I prevent closing of the modal when 'Cancel' is selected on SweetAlert2?

Tags: sweetalert2

[image: SweetAlert2 simple inbox modal]

I don't want the modal to close when I click the 'cancel(delete)' button, only when losing focus or close button is clicked. How can I prevent closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default cancel button is for closing the dialog. instead of hacking that button for another task, you can add custom buttons as html, and handle their click events manually: ([Run it live](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/dyMVYmj?editors=1010))

```
var onBtnClicked = (btnId) => {
  // Swal.close();
  alert("you choosed: " + btnId);
};
Swal.fire({
  title: "What you want to do?",
  icon: "warning",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  showCloseButton: true,
  html: `
     <p>select an action</p>
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onBtnClicked('reply')">Reply</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="onBtnClicked('delete')">Delete</button>
    </div>`
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of swal for deny and confirm actions you can just return false in preConfirm and preDeny functions in order to prevent modal closing, like:

```
Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Title',
        footer: 'Footer text',
        allowOutsideClick: false,
        allowEscapeKey: false,
        showConfirmButton: true,
        showDenyButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
        denyButtonText: 'Deny',
        preConfirm: () => {
            console.log('Confirm pressed!');
            return false;
        },
        preDeny: () => {
            console.log('Deny pressed!');
            return false;
        },
```